# Error display on Setup upgrade command

Tags: magento-2.1, error, command-line

I am facing an error while running command

```
bin/php magento setup:upgrade
```

It return the error shown below:

> [Magento\Setup\Exception] Database user does not have enough privileges. Please make sure SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER privileges are granted to table 'magento_latest'.

Comment: Are you trying in localhost ?

Comment: host => localhost in env.php

Comment: Change it to 127.0.0.1 
And then try again. Also make sure that your base url starts with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Ok i have changed it to 127.0.0.1
But now getting these error.

[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 
[PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: Try using sudo.  sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Tried sudo. But error remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check your database username and password. Before you proceed to this step, you should have already set up the database in MySQL. You need to create a user and grant access privileges to that user.

Answer (score 1):

Magento `2.1.x` checks for the respective privileges to be given in `\Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator::checkDatabasePrivileges`.
It looks for an exact match of the privileges in either `information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES` or `.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` but neglects to combine both results, as MySQL would do when executing SQL statements.

Magento also checks for the exact `current_user()`[(reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) to be matched.
But sometimes privileges in MySQL are granted via wildcards e.g. `'%'`.

Magento **only** finds privileges if you grant to the connecting user explicitly: Try

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mage\_db`.* TO 'mage_user'@'localhost';
```

instead of

```sql
[...] TO 'mage_user'@'%'
```